# Datadog monitor API/terraform process monitor check

Tags: api, monitor, terraform, datadog

I'm trying to integrate a Datadog monitor check on sshd process in my terraform codebase, but I'm getting `datadog_monitor.host_is_up2: error updating monitor: API error 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["The value provided for parameter 'query' is invalid"]}`

What I did was to copy the monitor's query I created on the Datadog panel and pasted it into the tf file:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "host_is_up2" {
  name = "host is up"
  type = "metric alert"
  message = "Monitor triggered"
  escalation_message = "Escalation message"

  query = "process.up.over('process:ssh').last(4).count_by_status()"

  thresholds {
    ok = 0
    warning = 1
    critical = 2
  }

  notify_no_data = false
  renotify_interval = 60

  notify_audit = false
  timeout_h = 60
  include_tags = true
  silenced {
    "*" = 0
  }
}
```

ofc the query example `"avg(last_1h):avg:aws.ec2.cpu{environment:foo,host:foo} by {host} > 2"` works

What's the right way to check via Datadog API or terraform if a specific service, like sshd, is up or not?

Comment: Datadog has online chat windows after you login, normally you can get answer directly. This will be first contact for your issue. If the problem is fixed, please update here.

Answer (score 2):

There are two error in your code:

1. The `type` used is wrong. It should be `service check` instead of `metric alert`.
2. You need to enclose `process.up` in a pair of `''`.

Once done, your code will run flawlessly.

Comment: Just tested it on my end, confirmed that's correct. You can also use `"` quotes if you escape them as `\"`